# Calling an object from another class

Tags: java, object

Trying to call the `Name` object from the `Name` class to my `Type` class but I have no idea how to. I'm doing this because later on I wanted to add price into each object too which is why I did it this way

```
    public class Name {

        public static void main(String [] args) {
            NameS hotel = new NameS();
            hotel.setName("1. Shangri-La");
            NameS hotel1 = new NameS();
            hotel1.setName("2. Pullman");
            NameS hotel2 = new NameS();
            hotel2.setName("3. Royal Chulan");

            NameS[]hotellist = new NameS [3];
            hotellist[0] = hotel;
            hotellist[1] = hotel1;
            hotellist[2] = hotel2;

            for (int i=0;i<hotellist.length;i++)
            {
                hotellist[i].print();
            }


            NameS mall = new NameS();
            mall.setName("1. 1Utama");
            NameS mall1 = new NameS();
            mall1.setName("2. Paradigm");
            NameS mall2 = new NameS();
            mall2.setName("3. Curve");

            NameS[]malllist = new NameS [3];
            malllist[0] = mall;
            malllist[1] = mall1;
            malllist[2] = mall2;

            for (int i=0;i<malllist.length;i++)
            {
                malllist[i].print();
            }

            NameS restaurant = new NameS();
            restaurant.setName("1. Nandos");
            NameS restaurant1 = new NameS();
            restaurant1.setName("2. Kura");
            NameS restaurant2 = new NameS();
            restaurant2.setName("3. Dining at Sky");

            NameS[]restaurantlist = new NameS [3];
            restaurantlist[0] = restaurant;
            restaurantlist[1] = restaurant1;
            restaurantlist[2] = restaurant2;

            for (int i=0;i<restaurantlist.length;i++)
            {
                restaurantlist[i].print();
            }


        }
   }
```

And the Type class

```
public class Type extends Homepage {

     public static void main(String [] args) {
            ArrayList<ReviewArrayList> list = new ArrayList <ReviewArrayList>();

            String mall;
            String restaurant;
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            int choice = 0;
            System.out.println("==============================");
            System.out.println("      Type of Facilities      ");
            System.out.println("==============================");
            System.out.println("1. Hotel");
            System.out.println("2. Shopping Mall");
            System.out.println("3. Restaurant");
            System.out.println("Choice > ");
            choice = input.nextInt();
            if(choice == 1) {

                System.out.println(hotel.getName());
                System.out.println(hotel1.getName());
                System.out.println(hotel2.getName());
        }   
    }
 }
```

Comment: why do you have two main class

Comment: Could you describe what exactly you are trying to do ? Not about the code. Just simple try to describe what exactly you want to do with this code. What you are taking from user and what you want to give output

Comment: The user can choose from 1-3 Option and after the input it will display a List of object or items in that option. Like if i enter 1 which is Hotel , a list of hotel will appear, but my hotel are all declared in the Name class and I'm trying to call it in the Type class

Comment: Please edit your question and post a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and format that code. Do not add answers, this is not a forum.Do not add comments. Take the tour of the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `main` method of the `Name` class, you create an `Array` named `hotellist` of `NameS` objects, which you then ignore.

My suggestion would be to make `hotellist`, `malllist`, and `restaurantlist` public static *class fields*. This would mean that your `type` class would be able to access them. For example:

```
public class Name {

public static NameS[] hotelList = new NameS[3];
public static NameS[] mallList = new NameS[3];
public static NameS[] restaurantList = new NameS[3];

public static void main(String[] args) {

    NameS hotel = new NameS();
    hotel.setName("1. Shangri-La");
    NameS hotel1 = new NameS();
    hotel1.setName("2. Pullman");
    NameS hotel2 = new NameS();
    hotel2.setName("3. Royal Chulan");

    hotelList[0] = hotel;
    hotelList[1] = hotel1;
    hotelList[2] = hotel2;

    for (int i=0;i<hotelList.length;i++)
    {
        hotelList[i].print();
    }


    NameS mall = new NameS();
    mall.setName("1. 1Utama");
    NameS mall1 = new NameS();
    mall1.setName("2. Paradigm");
    NameS mall2 = new NameS();
    mall2.setName("3. Curve");

    mallList[0] = mall;
    mallList[1] = mall1;
    mallList[2] = mall2;

    for (int i=0;i<mallList.length;i++)
    {
        mallList[i].print();
    }

    NameS restaurant = new NameS();
    restaurant.setName("1. Nandos");
    NameS restaurant1 = new NameS();
    restaurant1.setName("2. Kura");
    NameS restaurant2 = new NameS();
    restaurant2.setName("3. Dining at Sky");

    restaurantList[0] = restaurant;
    restaurantList[1] = restaurant1;
    restaurantList[2] = restaurant2;

    for (int i=0;i<restaurantList.length;i++)
    {
        restaurantList[i].print();
    }
```

Now, in your `Type` class, you can simply say

```
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    ArrayList<ReviewArrayList> list = new ArrayList <ReviewArrayList>();

    String mall;
    String restaurant;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int choice = 0;
    System.out.println("==============================");
    System.out.println("      Type of Facilities      ");
    System.out.println("==============================");
    System.out.println("1. Hotel");
    System.out.println("2. Shopping Mall");
    System.out.println("3. Restaurant");
    System.out.println("Choice > ");
    choice = input.nextInt();
    if(choice == 1) {
        System.out.println(Name.hotelList[0].getName());
        System.out.println(Name.hotelList[1].getName());
        System.out.println(Name.hotelList[2].getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: I know this is gonna be a silly question , but after i entered option 1 it give me this error   ( Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Type.main(Type.java:43)   )

Comment: ( Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at Type.main(Type.java:43)

Comment: @LeeKin Is line 43 the line where you have `choice = input.nextInt();`?

Comment: I have no idea why it would say line 43 but the entire code only have 29 line of codes, but it was pointing to this :(System.out.println(Name.hotelList[0].getName());

Comment: @LeeKin Here are some things I would check. 1. Do you have a `NameS` class written? 2. Do you have a `ReviewArrayList` class written? 3. Are all your `hotelList`s capitalized correctly (lowercase `hotel`, capital `L`, lowercase `ist`)? Are all your `restaurantList`s and `mallList`s? **This one is the most important to check. I noticed in my answer that mine are not all capitalized correctly**

Comment: @Sam I just fixed my capitilization in my answer

Comment: Yes I do have a NameS Class written and it only contains all the set and get method. I also did change to Upper case for all three of them. As for the ReviewArrayList that is just a mistake that i forgot to comment it out. Will the program work without the arraylist?

Comment: @LeeKin It should, but there could be something wrong with either the code I wrote or the code you wrote that we aren't seeing

Comment: @LeeKin I would try `NameS n = new NameS();`, `System.out.println(n.setName("1").getName());` as a test

Comment: On an entire new class or should i do it in the name class?

Comment: Do it in the Type class instead of your `if(choice == 1)` statement. It's a temporary change to test if something is wrong with your `Type` class

Comment: (n.setName("1").getName()) is invalid because it cannot invoke getName on the primitive type void  or so it says on the compiler

Comment: @LeeKin Alright, that's fine. Now try this: `NameS n = new NameS();`, `n.setName("1");`, `System.out.println(n.getName());` in place of the other testing code

Answer (score 0):

Just say

```
private Name name = new Name();

void() {
    /*name.objectName; calls the Object objectName that is inside the class Name*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you call an object from your current class...
By making a public method you can reach you fields from other classes.
But if I was you I would just make a constructor for applying the name from the beginning :)

```
public class Name
{
    private String name;

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

public class Main
{
    Name myName = new Name();

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        myName.setName("Marc");
    }

}
```